# Installing pyQt QWebKitWidget

Tags: python-3.x, qwebview

Can someone please clarify what is QWebKit? I told it was just another widget from PyQt that allows to show webpages inside a gui. 
Then I understood that with PyQt5 it doesn't come installed with PyQt anymore and I am not sure where to find it or how to install it on MAC.

I want a simple interface that changes the information shown in a page. I struggle to layout those information with the common PyQt widgets, so if I can relate all that to a simple HTML page to be shown inside a PyQt QWebView (with no CSS limitations) that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Apparently QWebKit was deprecated on Qt5.6 or Qt5.7 (can't remember).

The continued version of that tool and API calls is [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) and I guess what you want is QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()